# Not able to execute Script(.sh) inside script(.sh) with rensi.sshnet library in C# web application

Tags: c#, bash, shell, web

I have created a web application where I am executing a shell scrip `abc.sh` in a remote unix server. I am able to execute that script. But from `abc.sh` I am calling another script `xyz.sh`, which is not called. I am using `Rensi.sshnet` library to execute shell scripts in a web application.

Folder structure for Script files: `/home/scripts/`

**Note** : They both reside in same folder.

`abc.sh` looks like this:

```
echo test

echo "execute another shell script"

xyz.sh

echo "Executed"
```

Please provide me a solution or some work around to get the desired result.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your `xyz.sh` file is not in your `PATH`. Try change this line

```
xyz.sh
```

Into

```
./xyz.sh
```

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right. It works fine with your suggession. but I dont have anyrights to make changes for script file.

If I run that script file from "SSH.net Secure shell" tool it works absolutely fine with "xyz.sh".

Is there any specific reason why it doesnt work with "Rensi ssh.net" library in web application.

Comment: Maybe the reason is that there are environment variables set in your SSH.net secure shell, but you have not these variables set in your remote script execution. The SSH.net secure shell is an login shell, it means that after you open this shell all of your environment variables set automatically. You can do a trick in 'invocation' of the script, not the script itself. Add the path of containing folder on sever side before the invocation, like: invocation_func("PATH=$PATH:/remote_path abc.sh"). Another suggestion is invoke the script with bash shell, not sh shell (if it's possible)

Comment: I can't change it to BASH. I tried to call the script with PATH but didn't get the result. Can you just elaborate more on how to invoke the script adding the path of containing folder on server side?